# Bash: receive messages from background process

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, command-line-tool

I'm sending data via `cansend` to `vcan0`, at the same time I'm listening to messages that has been send to `vcan0` using the `candump vcan0` command

For some reason, i won't receive any messages, when sending data to `vcan0` through the script, but when i send data through terminal, the script receives data, somehow.

```
cansend vcan0 004#0152FEE400000000 # trying to send data (doesnt work)
while true;
do
  msg_candump=$(candump vcan0) # read vcan0
  if [[ ${#msg_candump} > 1 ]]; then #received msg
    echo $msg_candump
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using hash character <kbd>#</kbd> as data to send but this character
reserved to comment in shells

Try it like that:

```
( # Let run listener in background before trying to send to CAN
  while true;
  do
    msg_candump="$(candump vcan0 -T 1000)" # read CAN for 1 second
    if [[ ${#msg_candump} > 1 ]]; then #received msg
      echo "$msg_candump"
    fi
    sleep 0.025 # Give system a little breath
  done
) &
PID=$!

cansend vcan0 '004#0152FEE400000000' # <- quotes are matter 
sleep 5
kill -9 $PID
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. i added `msg_candump="$(candump vcan0 -T 1000)"` to this and it works now.

Comment: @david114 No problem, Im glad it helped you. I added `-T 1000` option to the answer, so it might be helpful for some1 else